# Conversion from built in types to Custom Classes

Tags: c++, casting

I have a custom class that acts as an int called Integer, I would like to tell compiler how to convert certain types to Integer automatically so that I can avoid typing same thing over and over again,

```
someCall(Integer(1), Integer(2));
```

would become

```
someCall(1,2);
```

I've googled but all I could find is to do the oposite, casting Integer to int I would like to accomplish the opposite.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Write a constructor that takes `int`, as:

```
class Integer
{
   public:
       Integer(int);
};
```

If the class `Integer` has this constructor, then you can do this:

```
void f(Integer);

f(Integer(1)); //okay 
f(1);          //this is also okay!
```

The explanation is that when you write `f(1)`, then the constructor of `Integer` that takes a single argument of type `int`, is automatically called and creates a temporary on the fly and and then that temporary gets passed to the function!

---

Now suppose you want to do exactly the opposite, that is, passing an object of type `Integer` to a function takes `int`:

```
 void g(int); //NOTE: this takes int!

 Integer intObj(1);
 g(intObj); //passing an object of type Integer?
```

To make the above code work, all you need is, define a user-defined conversion function in the class as:

```
class Integer
{
   int value;
   public:
       Integer(int);
       operator int() { return value; } //conversion function!
};
```

So when you pass an object of type `Integer` to a function which takes `int`, then the conversion function gets invoked and the object implicity converts to `int` which then passes to the function as argument. You can also do this:

```
int i = intObj; //implicitly converts into int
                //thanks to the conversion function!
```

Comment: You should ideally convert to `int&` and `const int&`, I think.

Comment: Nawaz what you suggest works but, I have return (n<2) ? 1 : IntegerFromACall; which gives me, error: operands to ?: have different types 'int' and 'Integer'

Comment: @Hamza: Write this : `return (n<2) ? 1 : (int)IntegerFromACall;`... This will work!

Comment: @DeadMG: I felt that. But I would like to hear more from you as to why do you suggest that? Do you want `intObj = 10` to work?

Answer (score 5):

You could define constructors in Integer for those types you want to implicitly convert. Do not make them `explicit`.

Answer (score 4):

Nawaz has given the correct answer. I just want to point out someting.
If the conversion operator is not const, you can't convert const objects

```
const Integer n(5);
int i = n; // error because non-const conversion operator cannot be called
```

Better declare your conversion operator as

```
operator int() const {return value;}
```